# output iteration results from a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to use a for loop to make some calculations in a cell array but at the end only the results for the last loop are displayed. I would like Matlab to display the results for all loops. Here there is the code:

```
slope=[];
time=[];
position= [];


for p=1:max(L)  % max L gives the number of result{n}. so if max(L)=6 we have from result{1} to result{6} and therefore 6 final values that i want to get%
   a=result{n}(:,1);
   b=result{n}(:,2);
end


B = [ones(length(a),1) a] \ b  % this is to obtain the slope and intercept of a lin. regresion

slope = B(2)

time = result{n}(end,1)-result{n}(1:1)
position = (slope.*result{n}(end,1)+intercept)-(slope.*result{n}(1:1)+intercept)
```

At the moment in the output that is what i get:

slope =

```
4.4089
```

time =

```
0.5794
```

position =

```
2.5546
```

This result is correct. However, these values are the ones obtained with result{6} and i need the values previous to this one.

Any help is much appreciated !

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mess with the indexes… It is a bit hard to understand what you did on your code, but it may be something like this (pseudocode since the code you gave does not have the `result` declared):

```
slope=zeros(1,max(L)); % Pre allocate zeros, one index for each interation
time=zeros(1,max(L));
position=zeros(1,max(L));
a=zeros(1,max(L));
b=zeros(1,max(L));

for p=1:max(L)  % max L gives the number of result{n}. so if max(L)=6 we have from result{1} to result{6} and therefore 6 final values that i want to get%
   a(p)=result{p}(:,1);
   b(p)=result{p}(:,2);
   B = [ones(length(a( p ),1) a( p )] \ b( p)  % this is to obtain the slope and intercept of a lin. regresion
   slope( p) = B(2)
   time( p) = result{p}(end,1)-result{p}(1:1)
   position( p) = (slope( p ).*result{p}(end,1)+intercept)-(slope ( p) .*result{p}(1)+intercept)
end
```

position(6) will get your value, position(5) the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to remove the ";" for lines that you want printed to the command window. This will display all loop values you need.

```
for p=1:max(L)
 a=result{n}(:,1)
 b=result{n}(:,2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do all calculations inside the loop and don't block with ";" instead. If you get a result after coming out of a loop, you will only get the last one.